I keep getting the same error when using input_dim and input_shape
When I specify the data with 11 attributes to the artificial neural network, I constantly get this error when using input_dim and input_shape. How can I fix this error?
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
classifer=Sequential() 
classifer.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(11,)))

Error:
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/dense.py:87: UserWarning: Do not pass an `input_shape`/`input_dim` argument to a layer. When using Sequential models, prefer using an `Input(shape)` object as the first layer in the model instead.
super().__init__(activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer, **kwargs)


Do you mean 'UserWarning:
Do not pass an input_shape/input_dim argument to a layer. When using Sequential models, prefer using an Input(shape) object as the first layer in the model instead.'?
This is a warning, not an error, and it also tells you how to fix it. See https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/ for an example of how to use Input(shape).

Thanks for answered
